# PHP Trait method works only on first load

Tags: php, traits

I'm using MAMP with PHP 5.4.10 and I have a problem with the following MWE:

```
<?php
trait T {
    public function hello() { echo 'hello'; }
}
class A {
    use T;
}
$a = new A();
$a->hello();
?>
```

The page shows 'hello' on the first load. But then, when I hit refresh, I get an Error 500.

If I modify the file (just by adding an empty line somewhere for instance) and refresh again, 'hello' shows up again. Hit refresh again, and the Error 500 is back.

Any clue where this might be coming from?

**Update:**

This shows up in the PHP errors log (nothing in the Apache errors log): `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method A::0?
                                                                                    ()`

(the `0` doesn't always have the same name when I repeat the operation).

Comment: Was the an error message in your error logs?

Comment: How do I access the error logs?

Comment: `How do I access the error logs?` google this!

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", "on");` on top of your script ... to see the real error

Comment: @Baba. 500 is regulary logged by apache, not php

Comment: Ok, googled it, and I updated my question with the error.

Comment: `I get an Error 500` Do you really mean, that a HTTP 500 status code is sent back?

Comment: Are you running APC or similar?

Comment: @hek2mgl: This is the message I got from Chrome. Actually, this is kind of strange: sometimes I get no message, and sometimes in get an error 324 (in which case I also have an Apache error: `[notice] child pid 18502 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`.
@AlexHowansky: nope, nothing like that.

Comment: I expect that your real code is more than that you've posted here. Can you reproduce the problem with the simple example?

Answer (score 1):

Xcache might be the problem here, try turning caching off (or at least xcache) and try it again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and thanks to the @Leon Weemen i focused on the XCache. I found [this bug](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ticket/295) (which is fixed in XCache 3.0.1) to be exactly what causes the problem (my version of XCache was 2.0.0). They suggest you to set in your php.ini the following values to solve the problem;

```
xcache.mmap_path = "/tmp/xcache"
xcache.readonly_protection = on
```

However, this workaround does not solve the problem for me. The only way I was able to disable the XCache was by using the `ini_set()` PHP method. The following snippet at the very begginning of my application solves the problem and is ready to use XCache as soon as it is updated:

```
try{
    $xCache = new ReflectionExtension('xcache');
    if(version_compare($xCache->getVersion(), '3.0.1', '<')){
        ini_set('xcache.cacher', 0);
    }
} catch(ReflectionException $e){
    // xCache not installed - everything should work fine
}
```